# Find duplicates, sum corresponsive and post the sums in a new column Excel VBA

Tags: excel, sum, duplicates, vba

I'm new here, but i hope i can get an answer to my question anyway 
I tried searching for my problem but couldn't find a thread so sorry if there's already a similar thread.

I have several files that contains several lists in columns A to T. I need to find duplicates in a column and sum the corresponsive cells which are in a different column and then add the result in a new column. 
I already have a code that does what i need but not exactly how i want it. The problem is this code write the results in the same row as the first (name) of the duplicates. So if my list is like this it'll write the result like shown below:

```
A B C
a 5 10
a 2 
a 3
b 2 6
b 3
b 1
c 4 7
c 1
c 2
```

I want it to write the results in rows 1,2 and 3 instead of showing blanks until the "right" row. I also want to carry over the name of the type next to the results. Like so:

```
Name Results
a 10
b 6
c 7
```

`

```
Sub sample()

Dim lastRow As Integer, num As Integer, i As Integer
lastRow = Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 14 To lastRow
num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 3), Range("C1:C" & lastRow), 0)
If i = num Then
Cells(i, 25) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("C1:C" & lastRow), Cells(i, 3), Range("J1:J" & lastRow))
Cells(i, 25).Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

`

I've tried tweeking the code abit but i just don't get how to make it so i get what i need.. :/

Thanks for any help

Another problem i have with the code, if there's a blank row (which happens alot) the code only works for the rows until the blank then quit and tells me there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("c:c").Clear
For i = 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    alreadythere = False
    For k = 1 To i
        If Cells(k, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
            alreadythere = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next k
    If alreadythere = False Then
        Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 2)
      Else
        Cells(k, 3) = Cells(k, 3) + Cells(i, 2)
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```